# Problem with INSERT INTO statement, new to access

Tags: ms-access

I got thrown into a project at work and I'm trying to fight my way through it. I'm trying to write records to a table from a form. I want to select from two combo boxes and then send the selections plus the time to a table.

Here is what I have

```vb
Private Sub cmdClockin_Click()
 
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim Cin As Date
Dim Ein As String
Dim Jin As String

Cin = Now()
Ein = Me.ComboEmp
Jin = Me.comboJob

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Records (proStart, proEmployee, proJob) VALUES ('" & Cin & "', '" & Ein & "', '" & Jin & "');"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

I do not get any errors, but nothing gets written to the table.

I have been scouring different websites and for some reason I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be amazing

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Disable or discard the `DoCmd.SetWarnings` lines and execute your SQL statement like this: `CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL, dbFailOnError`  With that approach, what does Access say about why the record is not added?

Comment: This pointed me in the right directions. The error it came back with dealt with a primary key issue.  I don't currently understand what the primary key is, but by clearing it, I was able to get it to record the data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Insert *Now* directly, consider if *Ein* or *Jin* are numeric (thus no quotes), and do check your SQL:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Records (proStart, proEmployee, proJob) VALUES (Now(), '" & Ein & "', '" & Jin & "');"
MsgBox StrSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion change table name from `Records` to some other name. You need to qualify `time` as `Date/Time` by a hash `#` symbol instead of single quote (') for date data type. Check below

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Records (proStart, proEmployee, proJob) VALUES (#" & Cin & "#, '" & Ein & "', '" & Jin & "');"
```

Comment: Also make sure you have selected proper data to your comboboxes.